# Connecting a Pi to a laptop. How does it supply the address?

Tags: raspbian, windows

There are lots of answers to how to configure the network properties for both the Windows 10 Pro Laptop and a Raspberry Pi. What I have discovered is that, without any special configuration, when I connect my Pi to my laptop with an ethernet cable, the Pi gets an address from Windows 10, always in the 169.254.*.* network.  When I look at the network adapter for the laptop for the Ethernet connection it also has an 169.254.157.116 address.

What I have determined is that my laptop always gets the same address, 169.254.157.116.  When I connect Pi "A" to the laptop with the ethernet cable and from the Pi consol "ifconfig" I see this address 169.254.94.152. Rebooting both devices and repeating the experiment I get the same results.

If I connect a different Pi "B" the laptop address is the same but the Pi address is different, 169.254.2.51.  It is consistent like that for PI "A" experiments.

The same is true for still a third Pi. 169.254.253.10

So my question is "What Window 10 function is providing these addresses and are they predictable, perhaps via the MAC address?"

Thanks...RDK

Comment: I've wondered the same thing! Good question, +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows is not supplying these addresses. This feature is called [link-local addressing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address).

This self-addressing is a built-in part of the network stack. You can read the full details in [RFC 3927](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3927).

Each network interface generates the same IP address each time because it is based off of the interface's MAC (Layer-2) address (amongst other things), which is coded into the firmware of the interface's chip itself.